# Why aren't all Firebase dependencies updated in a full CocoaPods update?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

My `Podfile` is configured to update Firebase to all of the latest versions.

```
target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

However, when I run `pod outdated`, I notice that not all dependencies are set to update in the subsequent update, such as the following:

```
- gRPC-C++ 1.44.0 -> 1.44.0 (latest version 1.50.0)
- gRPC-Core 1.44.0 -> 1.44.0 (latest version 1.52.0-pre2)
```

Is this because Firebase has determined it does not want the latest version in this update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, FirebaseFirestore depends specifically on version 1.44.0 of gRPC-C++. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/10.4.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json#L87.

gRPC changed its C++ version in later releases that require some Firestore updates. A PR is in progress at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/10650